# How to apply Sen2cor in sen2r graphical user interface?

Tags: r, sentinel-2, sen2cor, rstudio

I have recently installed the sen2r plugin in r for extracting level 1 Sentinel-2 images from ESA's Long Term Archive and using sen2cor correction to obtain level 2 scenes.

An issue I face is that the GUI seems to not let you apply sen2cor. It says that level 2 images are required. I have tried to use the standalone sen2cor processor which comes as a part of sen2r() package in R, but not all scenes get corrected.

Does anyone have experienced something similar or can provide guidance with this?

Comment: Is it a must do step the use of sen2cor over L1C images? You can donwload S2-L2A images, which are already corrected by sen2cor

Comment: That is true, but S2_L2A images only go back to December of 2018 (at least in Google Earth Engine it shows that) and I am trying to incorporate older images. Unfortunately the OpenHub is down for a few days, so I can't verify this, but I think the older scenes are just L1C

Comment: I used to correct S2 L1C images with sen2cor from CMD/terminal window. I created batch orders in R with `paste0`, saving the sentences into a batch file. It's kinda easy if you have all the S2 folders in one single folder. I have no experience in the use of sen2r tho, so I can't help you with package usage

Comment: Check `L2A_Process --help` in CMD/terminal window and see if sen2cor is correctly installed

Comment: I checked to see if sen2cor is correctly installed and it seems to be fine. I would like to try doing it your way, outside sen2r. Could you provide your batch file for that, if you still have it?

Comment: Sadly I don't have it, but you only need paste the `L2A_Process --resolution 10 ` with the .SAFE folders and modify L2A_GIPP.xml file for atmosphere / terrain correction configuration. Check for usage: http://step.esa.int/thirdparties/sen2cor/2.8.0/docs/S2-PDGS-MPC-L2A-SUM-V2.8.pdf

Comment: Okey I see how this has to be done now, thanks for the help! If you want some credits, formulate your answer and I'll approve it as the answer that answered the question

Comment: You're welcomed. Thanks for thinking about the credits, but what I told you don't resolve your initial question. It wouldn't be fair for others. Cheers!